# update code and reflect the changes in AEM CQ5

Tags: aem

How to see instantly update the code and see that it is reflected without firing up Maven Clean Install again and again in AEM CQ5 project? I know it can be possible through JRebel in normal Java projects. But I am not sure in AEM Projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sync repository items with [vault](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/dev-tools/ht-vlttool.html). One at a time or with vault sync. There vault plugins available for both Eclipse and IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm. I installed intelliVault plugin and started pushing the updated files using Push to CRX option. But Is there anyway to push these updated files on Save? .

Comment: @Rakesh you can configure a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ to save and push. But there's no way to do it automatically that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by jiggy, code changes in /apps(component jsps ..), /etc (css, js..), etc can be synced with AEM using vault plugin. This does not require rebuild/package/deploy to AEM using 'mvn clean install'.
Server side(java files) changes however requires firing up 'maven clean install' and installing the new generated bundle either manually or automatically via profiles in maven POM to AEM.

Comment: Thank you Subhash.